# What is the standard deviation of an uniformly distributed random variable X?

Tags: probability

I got a variance of $1/12$, which should give me a standard deviation of $1/ \sqrt(12) $, but apparently it is $\sqrt(3)/6$.

Comment: If $X\sim\mathtt{Uni}([0,1])$, then $\frac{1}{12}$ is the correct answer. Perhaps you misquoted the question; what is $n$ anyway?

Comment: Can you specify the problem, because $n$ isn't specified anywhere

Comment: Use $\sqrt{E[X]^2-(E[X])^2}$.  Also uniform over what interval?  Is it [0,1]?  Or you could have [0,n]?

Comment: it's a typo, sorry.

Comment: i was looking for the standard deviation, which is supposed to be $\sqrt(3)/6$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is just fine, it only requires some simplification. Some people don't like having square roots in their denominator.
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}\frac{\sqrt{12}}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{\sqrt{4\times 3}}{12}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{12}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of seeing this is 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{4} \cdot \sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}
$$